# LuaTeX: matrix in equation trows "missing number, treaded as zero" Error

Tags: math-mode, luatex, amsmath, matrices, optional-arguments

**Solved:** I had declared an algorithm just before this equation, in it I did set \SetKwArray{array}{array}. I changed it to \SetKwArray{arraq}{array}, works fine now.

This is my document. It throws error:

> Missing number, treated as zero. 
>   \begin{matrix} (By unicode-math-luatex.sty in Line 227). I cannot fix it. I tried:
>   -- Optional Argument after \ (Fix: \{})
>   -- Optional Argument after &  (Fix: &{})
>   -- Load/unload various packages

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Für mathematische Symbole
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\usepackage{import}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[ 
spelling = new, 
babelshorthands = true ]
{german}

% Für Pseudo-Code
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

% Durchstreichen
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

%Hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}

% Aside Kommentar
\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar

% Package für bessere Liste
\usepackage{scrextend}

 % Coole Listen [Seperator-zeichen]
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}

% \emph{} - ändern
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\bfseries}

%Für Farben
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{TextMarkerGelb}{RGB}{255, 255, 120}
\usepackage{soul}
\sethlcolor{TextMarkerGelb}

% Paragraph-Einstellung
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\uline{#1}}
\titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[block]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\uline{#1.}}

%Roboto-Font: https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Roboto
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Roboto}
\setsansfont{Roboto}
\setmonofont{Roboto}
\setmathfont{Asana Math} % for math symbols, can be any other OpenType math font
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {Roboto}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Roboto}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Roboto}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {Roboto}

% O-Notation
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

%Bibliographie-Verwaltung
\usepackage{biblatex}

%Ermöglicht [H]
\usepackage{float}

%Integral d
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

%Counter Alphabetisch statt zahlen
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
        \begin{matrix}
        [1] & [2] & [3] &  [4] &  [5] &  [6] &  [7] &  [8] \cr   
        3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 17 & 19 & 13 & 14
    \end{matrix}
    \end{equation}


\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Edit: uploaded log-file: https://pastebin.com/DzBFsvUs

Comment: Works for me with LuaLaTeX on TL18.

Comment: @TeXnician Strange, I just found out \bigl( and \bigr) doesn´t work for me either :(. Mathtools loads amsmath, am I right?

Comment: Yes. Could you show your log file?

Comment: Is there a way to upload a file? Copy & paste takes to many chars, as it says.

Comment: Can you reduce your example then? Does the error still occur without hyperref? biblatex? fontspec? By making it more minimal you also help us help you because possible causes are easier to identify.

Comment: I unloaded almost every package but error persists. I uploaded the log file see edit.

Comment: Then you maybe just want to update your packages (using MikTeX updater/console).

Comment: @TeXnician I did reinstall Miktex and it did not help. I just found the problem. Just before that matrix, I declared \SetKwArray{array}{array} in an \begin{agorithm}-enviroment. I change it to \SetKwArray{arraq}{array} and know it works fine, but thank you very much for providing a problem-solving-flow :) Thx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error was due to a piece of code not shown in the MWE.